# iPad Full-Screen Mode Allow Browsing

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari, kiosk-mode

I would like to use `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` to allow a user to browse a website like a kiosk, without the navigation bar and the page fullscreen.

This works well until a link is clicked, then it opens Safari.

**Is there any way to use this fullscreen mode and allow clicking of links without being taken to Safari?**

Comment: I asked a similar question over on AskDifferent - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89682/hiding-url-bar-on-ipad.  There is a solution but it is more complicated then just flipping a switch, and it may not be appropriate for all environments.

Comment: Also... if you have control over what browser your audience is using (i.e., this is a controlled device) you could try Chrome.  I believe it has a full screen mode.

Comment: Yes, I do have control over the browsing experience as this iPad will be in a Kiosk. This might have to be the route we go. Want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question over on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) - [Hiding URL Bar on iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89682/hiding-url-bar-on-ipad).

The answer I received there suggested distributing the web app's configuration file, which allows you to configure many more options.  The end-user must agree to the profile installation, but having a controlled device will limit any frustration with this fact.  The details of this were linked to in the above answer, but it appears to be broken now.

Alternatively, Chrome has a full screen browser mode that can be taken advantage of.  Given a controlled device you could simply use the alternative browser.